# How can I baseline-align two blocks with different font-height?

Tags: xsl-fo

I've got a table with 2 cells. One cell contains a number, the other contains text in a larger font. I want to align the baselines of the two texts. I've tried lots of combinations of display-align, vertical-align, alignment-baseline etc. Nothing seems to work: the blocks are always aligned as if alignment-baseline="center".

```
<fo:table>
    <fo:table-column column-width="20mm" column-number="1"/>
    <fo:table-column column-width="100mm" column-number="2"/>
    <fo:table-body>
       <fo:table-row>
           <fo:table-cell column-number="1">
               <fo:block font-size="9pt" line-height="22pt">1.</fo:block>
           </fo:table-cell>
           <fo:table-cell column-number="2">
               <fo:block font-size="20pt"line-height="22pt">Title</fo:block>
           </fo:table-cell>
       </fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
```

I can fake the correct alignment by putting a padding on the block in column 1, but I'd rather use a non-hack solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `relative-align="baseline"`.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#relative-align

`relative-align` exists because of this problem.  It applies only to `fo:table-cell` and `fo:list-item` since they are (or were expected to be) the only places where it's needed.